# How to change styles of multiple buttons and add slide animation in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have 3 button. I want to add red `background` when one of them is clicked. By default the first button is active. When I click on the second or the third one first button should lose it's background styles red to gray. Also I want to add slide in animation. ex, If I'm currently on first button and click on the 2nd button, background should animate left to right.
[image: Three buttons]

My current code:

```
import React from "react";

const TopOptions = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col border-b shadow-lg">
        <div className="flex flex-col px-4">
          <p className="text-xs pl-6 pt-4">PUNE</p>
          <div className="flex flex-row items-center">
            <select className="pl-2">
              <option value="Kothrud Outlet">Kothrud Outlet</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className=" bg-gray-100 my-5 text-center flex flex-row items-center justify-evenly text-sm rounded-md mx-4">
          <button className="w-full py-3 font-bold ">DELIVERY</button>
          <button className="w-full py-3 font-bold text-gray-600">
            TAKEAWAY
          </button>
          <button className="w-full py-3 font-bold text-gray-600">
            DINE IN
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TopOptions;
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to replace your hardcoded buttons with an array getting rendered, and include a `state` variable in your app that stores with slide is currently active.

Comment: Could you help me here with some more info? I'm not very great at this.

Comment: This is really basic React stuff, I can't provide free tutorials here obviously that are already on the official React website anyway. I recommend you start here and learn all the basic concepts first: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by giving each button a number, initialise a state variable with the number of the first button and change this state on each btn press:

```
    import React, {useState} from "react";

export const TopOptions = () => {
    const [clickedButton, setClickedButton] = useState(0);
    const [yPos, setYPos] = useState(0);
    const buttons = ["DELIVERY", "TAKEAWAY", "DINE IN"];


    const speed = 10;
    let direction = 0;
    const updateState = () => {
        setYPos(yPos + (speed * direction));
    }

    const clickHandler = (index) => {
        direction = index > clickedButton ? 1 : -1;
        let duration = Math.abs(clickedButton - index) * 1000; // 1sec
        setClickedButton(index);
        const animRef = requestAnimationFrame(updateState);
        setTimeout(() => {
            cancelAnimationFrame(animRef);
        }, duration);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="flex flex-col border-b shadow-lg">
                <div className="flex flex-col px-4">
                    <p className="text-xs pl-6 pt-4">PUNE</p>
                    <div className="flex flex-row items-center">
                        <select className="pl-2">
                            <option value="Kothrud Outlet">Kothrud Outlet</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div
                    className=" bg-gray-100 my-5 text-center flex flex-row items-center justify-evenly text-sm rounded-md mx-4">
                    {buttons.map((btn, index) => (
                        <button className={"w-full py-3 font-bold " + (clickedButton === index ? "" : "text-gray-600")}
                                onClick={() => {
                                    clickHandler(index);
                                }} key={"btn" + index}
                        >{btn}</button>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <image src={"yourbackgroundimage.jpg"}
                       style={"position:fixed; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; top: 0; left: " + yPos}/>
                {
                    /*
                    This is not a god example, just to show how to use yPos now.
                    assuming left btn is curently active:
                    if clicked on middle button it lets the image slide from left to right for one second
                    if clicked on right button it lets the image slide from left to right for two second
                     */
                }
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks but I want the first button by default red. Can you think of something else?

Comment: with this code the first button should be red, didn't test it but I'm pretty sure. Full paste: https://pastebin.com/p9mQ2cp0
edit sry i messed up, here the new paste

Comment: Dude, you are a life saver. Can't thank you enough. Is there any way that I can add slide effect I mentioned in my problem?

Comment: added animation in the edit, hope this works as intended, you may have to change the -1 and 1 for the direction in the click handler, didn't tested it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use state for each individual button's class. After clicking each button you have to change that button's state as per following:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const TopOptions = () => {

    const [btnClass, setBtnClass] = useState({"delivery": "btn-danger", "takeaway": "", "dinein": ""});

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        // after handling the click event add following code
        let updatedBtnClass = {"delivery": "", "takeaway": "", "dinein": ""};
        updatedBtnClass[e.target.name] = "btn-danger"; // for red background class
        setBtnClass(updatedBtnClass);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="flex flex-col border-b shadow-lg">
                <div className="flex flex-col px-4">
                    <p className="text-xs pl-6 pt-4">PUNE</p>
                    <div className="flex flex-row items-center">
                        <select className="pl-2">
                            <option value="Kothrud Outlet">Kothrud Outlet</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div
                    className=" bg-gray-100 my-5 text-center flex flex-row items-center justify-evenly text-sm rounded-md mx-4">
                    <button name={"delivery"} className={"w-full py-3 font-bold " + btnClass.delivery} onClick={handleClick}>
                        DELIVERY
                    </button>
                    <button name={"takeaway"} className={"w-full py-3 font-bold " + btnClass.takeaway}  onClick={handleClick}>
                        TAKEAWAY
                    </button>
                    <button name={"dinein"} className={"w-full py-3 font-bold " + btnClass.dinein} onClick={handleClick}>
                        DINE IN
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default TopOptions;
```

Comment: It's working nice. Is there anyway that I can add the slide animation?